# Which is more appropriate - 'experience in design/experience in the design/experience in designing' ?

Tags: articles, definite-article, gerunds, zero-article

Consider the following sentences:

A: He has 2 years of experience in design and development of software.
B: He has 2 years of experience in the design and development of software.
C: He has 2 years of experience in designing and developing software.

Which of these sentences is more appropriate? Can we use 'the' as in sentence B here?

Comment: I cant answer the question, but I think "software development" is a better option

Comment: All three are acceptable. My preference is for "B."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option B is fine. Option C is also fine, but I think it sounds better without the "in":

> He has 2 years of experience designing and developing software.

I think I personally would go with something like this:

> He has 2 years of experience in software design and development.

"Software design" and "software development" are commonly-used terms that refer to areas of expertise.